# Is my proof sufficient for "Prove that $C(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $H \leq G $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $$ C(H) = \{ g \in G : gh=hg \quad \forall h \in H \}$$

Prove that $C(H)$ is a subgroup of G.

Answer:

Since $ e = ee = ee \in C(H)$ then $ C(H) \neq \emptyset $.

If $f = g_1 h_1, k = g_2 h_2 \in C(H) $ then

$$ f k^{-1} = g_1h_1(g_2h_2)^{-1}=g_1h_1h_2^{-1}g_2^{-1}= g_1h_1g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1} = g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1}g_1h_1= k^{-1} f \in C(H)$$

Since $ g_i h_j = h_j g_i$ by definition.

Then by the One-Step Subgroup test, $ C(H) \leq G $.

Am I missing something? Seems rather trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why did you write $f,k$ as above? It is easy and the following may clear the proof! Let $a,b\in C_G(h)$ and let $h\in H$ arbitrary. Then we have:

$$
(ab^{-1})h=a(b^{-1}h)=a(h^{-1}b)^{-1}=a(bh^{-1})^{-1}=a(hb^{-1})=(ah)b^{-1}=(ha)b^{-1}=h(ab^{-1})
$$

This shows that for any $h\in H$, the element $ab^{-1}$ commutes with $h$ so it belongs to $C_G(H)$

Comment: Isn't the subgroup test to check if $a,b \in C(H)$ then $a b^{-1} \in C(H)$? Wouldnt it make sense to let $a = g_1 h_1 $ etc? What is $C_g (h)$ ?

Comment: Yes it is. Assuming $a$ as a product of two elements of $G$ and $H$ may bring up another stories about the group itself! What makes you to assume such this assumption(s)? I don't see it not in the title nor in the body. Moreover I think you used $C(H)$ as $C_G(H)$. Different notations but same meaning.

Comment: Alright, but why then use three elements in $ C_G(H)$? also, Since we do not know if $g_1 g_2^{-1} = g_2^{-1} g_1 $, how do you know that $b^{-1} h = h b^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Dear Oskar, It shouldn't be take from $C_G(H)$ but from $H$. As you see above there is a typo(My bad).

Comment: I see! But still, if $a,b \in C(H) $ is sufficient to show that $ab^{-1} \in C(H)$. How come you multiply with an arbitrary $h \in H$?

Comment: If you want to see whether $C_G(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$, you should show that for any $a,b$ of it $ab^{-1}$ is an element of $C_G(H)$. So it makes you to check if $(ab^{-1})h=h(ab^{-1})$ or not for any arbitrary $h\in H$

Comment: Doesn't makes sense to me though. How does $(ab^{-1})h \in C(H)$ imply that $ab^{-1} \in C(H)$?